# How to call a procedure inside another procedure and use it twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a procedure from the following code: (that uses another procedure inside)

```
SET @p0='87';
CALL `wm_ewallet_transactions_balance`(@p0);

with recursive rcte(user_id, balance, date) as (
  (
    select user_id, balance, date
    from  wm_ewallet_user_balance
    order by date
    limit 1
  )
union all
select coalesce(t.user_id, r.user_id),
    coalesce(t.balance, r.balance),
    r.date + interval 1 day
from rcte r
left join wm_ewallet_user_balance t on t.date = r.date + interval 1 day
where r.date < (select max(date) from wm_ewallet_user_balance)
)
select r.user_id, min(r.balance) as balance, r.date
from rcte r
group by r.user_id, r.date
order by r.date;
```

As you can see, in the second line, I've called another procedure named `wm_ewallet_transactions_balance`. It creates a **temporary table** named `wm_ewallet_user_balance` (and I've used that table three times)

The issue is it throws:

> #1137 - Can't reopen table: 'wm_ewallet_user_balance'

How can I fix it?

---

And here is the first procedure named `wm_ewallet_transactions_balance`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wm_ewallet_user_balance
(
    INDEX user_id_index (user_id),
    INDEX created_at_index (date)
)
SELECT
    id,
    user_id,
    type,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id) AS `balance`,
    created_at,
    date(created_at) AS date
FROM
    wm_ewallet_transactions
WHERE user_id = user_id_param
```

Comment: The error message comes from the procedure, it seems - and you did not show that part of the code.

Comment: the problem is that you can't use the temporary table twice in a query, so make simply two of them, while i can't see why you need the two indexes for one user_id

Comment: @nbk I need that temporary table three times .. honestly doesn't look optimal to me to create three temp tables with the same content .. isn't there any better approach?

Comment: @MartinAJ MySQL can't use them more than once, that is so and has not changed since ages, switch to mariadb, that has  not that limit, use a CTE without indexes or make three temporary tables

Comment: @nbk aha, could you please show me how can I use CTE in this case? I mean is it possible to use both `cte` and `rcte` after each other?

Comment: I did it this way https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/d50c9910272761890f94390df51274ad , but it does't work and throws `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't pretty and it doesn't use indexes, so you must check if a three times genrated temp table makes it faster

```
WITH  wm_ewallet_user_balance AS
(
SELECT
    id,
    user_id,
    type,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id) AS `balance`,
    created_at,
    date(created_at) AS date
FROM
    wm_ewallet_transactions
WHERE user_id = @p0)
SELECT * FROM (
             WITH recursive rcte(user_id, balance, date) as (
              (
                select user_id, balance, date
                from  wm_ewallet_user_balance
                order by date
                limit 1
              )
            union all
            select coalesce(t.user_id, r.user_id),
                coalesce(t.balance, r.balance),
                r.date + interval 1 day
            from rcte r
            left join wm_ewallet_user_balance t on t.date = r.date + interval 1 day
            where r.date < (select max(date) from wm_ewallet_user_balance)
            )
            select r.user_id, min(r.balance) as balance, r.date
            from rcte r
            group by r.user_id, r.date
            order by r.date) t1;
```

Comment: Yeah worked .. nice .. thank you buddy